# Powerful search-replace GUI app for Mac?

Tags: macos, replace, grep

What's the best dedicated search-and-replace GUI tool on a Mac? "Find & Replace It!" seems decent, but they've ridiculously disabled the replace function in the demo, so I can't give it a real test before paying. Is there anything else comparable or better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/) (free) or its big brother [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) (not free).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the version 1.0 of Find & Replace It! allows replacing in its trial version. Personnaly I like it for its preview feature and its scripting possibilities.

https://find-and-replace-it.com/

[update] New link

Comment: Here's the correct link: http://www.dprog.ch/home/products/find_and_replace_it/ Thanks to @Josh at http://superuser.com/a/118389/139697

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to pay a dime for anything! If your OS has bash/sed/find/etc and other *nix tools, you can do your own script to do find and replace!
eg if you have sed

```
sed -i.bak 's/find/replace/g' *.txt
```

Comment: I think the question asked for a GUI app.

Answer (score 1):

Huge overkill, but Eclipse's find and replace dialogue is pretty solid.  Supports regexes with excellent syntax help.

I was going to recommend sed as well, if it hadn't been for the gui requirement :)

Answer (score 1):

vim

```
:%s/pattern/replace/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Search&Replace over at http://searchreplaceapp.com/

Comment: This one doesn't work at all for me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to Replacr
http://replacr.com

Here you can read a review
http://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/replacr-for-os-x-batch-find-replace-text-in-txt-rtf-files/